# Consume Vector inside closure without cloning

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, unsafe

I have this data structure.

```rust
let bucket = HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>>
```

Given

```rust
let cluster = Vec<&str>
```

I want to expand it from the `Vec`s on Bucket and **I can guarantee that I will just access each key value pair once and the `&str` in `cluster` are always a key in `bucket`**.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut bucket: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
    bucket.insert("a", vec!["hello", "good morning"]);
    bucket.insert("b", vec!["bye", "ciao"]);
    bucket.insert("c", vec!["good"]);
    let cluster = vec!["a", "b"];
    let cluster2 = vec!["c"];
    let mut clusters = [cluster, cluster2];
    clusters.iter_mut().for_each(|cluster| {
        // I don't like this clone
        let tmp = cluster.clone();
        let tmp = tmp.iter().flat_map(|seq| bucket[seq].
            clone() // I really don't like this other clone
        );
        cluster.extend(tmp);
    });
    println!("{:?}", clusters);
}
```

This compiles but what I really want to do is drain the vector on `bucket` since I know I won't access it again.

```rust
let tmp = tmp.iter().flat_map(|seq| bucket.get_mut(seq).
    unwrap().drain(..)
);
```

That gives me a compiler error:

```rust
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:13:45
   |
4  |       let mut bucket: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
   |           ---------- variable defined here
...
13 |           let tmp = tmp.iter().flat_map(|seq| bucket.get_mut(seq).
   |                                             - ^-----
   |                                             | |
   |  ___________________________________________|_variable captured here
   | |                                           |
   | |                                           inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
14 | |             unwrap().drain(..)
   | |______________________________^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

Do I need to go unsafe? How? And more importantly, is it reasonable to want to remove that `clone`?

Comment: _"Do I need to go unsafe?"_ - This is almost never the answer. If the compiler is telling you that you are borrowing mutably and immutably at the same time, getting around that with unsafe will quite often lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PeterHall The thing is that the `Vec` _clusters_ are created from the keys of _bucket_ in the real program (and a key is just put once), but the compiler does not know that so it says, "hey, bucket, which is mutated, outlives the `FnMut` closure, that's very bad, you can't reuse it!". That's why I think that I need to go `unsafe` but there may be a safe solution to this where the compiler does not yell at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate `bucket[seq].clone()` using [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```
let tmp = tmp.iter().flat_map(
    |seq| std::mem::take(bucket.get_mut(seq).unwrap()),
);
```

That will transfer ownership of the existing `Vec` and leave an empty one in the hash map. Since the map remains in a well-defined state, this is 100% safe. Since the empty vector doesn't allocate, it is also efficient. And finally, since you can guarantee that you no longer access that key, it is correct. ([Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7683b5ca2bcde82e5e99e33860109b2d))

As pointed out in the comments, an alternative is to remove the vector from the hash map, which also transfer the ownership of the vector:

```
let tmp = tmp.iter().flat_map(|seq| bucket.remove(seq).unwrap());
```

The outer `cluster.clone()` cannot be replaced with `take()` because you need the old contents. The issue here is that you cannot extend the vector you are iterating over, which Rust doesn't allow in order to implement efficient pointer-based iteration. A simple and effective solution here would be to use indices instead of iteration ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7009295f54e14913fc01eb58a02bbd6f)):

```
clusters.iter_mut().for_each(|cluster| {
    let initial_len = cluster.len();
    for ind in 0..initial_len {
        let seq = cluster[ind];
        cluster.extend(std::mem::take(bucket.get_mut(seq).unwrap()));
    }
});
```

Of course, with indexing you pay the price of indirection and bound checks, but rustc/llvm is pretty good at removing both when it is safe to do so, and even if it doesn't, indexed access might still be more efficient than cloning. The only way to be sure whether this improves on your original code is to benchmark both versions on production data.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I had the vague idea that this `std::mem` existed, but I don't know how to use it confidently. Time to study it, I guess. Thank you so much!

Comment: @carrasco Glad it helped - although the borrow checker sometimes appear daunting, you very rarely _need_ unsafe when writing ordinary code. (You might need it to efficiently implement efficient data structures from scratch.) Also note that `std::mem::take()` is just a convenience wrapper for `std::mem::replace()`, which is the real beast. :)

Comment: You can use `HashMap::remove` instead of `mem::take` for values that don't have a `Default` implementation.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks, I've now updated the answer to mention it. (`std::mem::take()` is still useful for cases where you cannot easily remove, and few people know of it so I like to advertise it.)